# How to make checkbox work in dropdown using bootstrapvuejs

Tags: html, vue.js, bootstrap-vue

I am trying to get this drop down to work in bootstrapvuejs.

But for some reason it not allowing me to tick the boxes. how can i get the box to tick before the dropdown closes?

```
<template>
  <div class="inventory-filter-button">
    <b-dropdown id=InventoryFilterButton variant="transparent"  text="Split Link" checkbox-menu allow-focus :right="right">
      <template #button-content>
        <span>
          <font-awesome-icon size="1x" :icon="['fas', 'filter']"/>
        </span>
      </template>
      <b-dropdown-item>    
        <b-form-checkbox id="checkbox-1" v-model="status" name="checkbox-1" 
                         value="accepted" unchecked-value="not_accepted"> All 
        </b-form-checkbox>
      </b-dropdown-item>
      <b-dropdown-item>    
        <b-form-checkbox id="checkbox-1" v-model="status" name="checkbox-1"
                                                 value="accepted" unchecked-value="not_accepted"> Department 
        </b-form-checkbox>
      </b-dropdown-item>
    </b-dropdown>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    name: 'InventoryFilterButton.vue'
  };
</script>
    
<style scoped></style>
```

Comment: Looks like you want a Vue-multiselect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't add `<b-form-checkbox>` inside `<b-dropdown-item>`.

- To fix the issue you have to add `<b-form-checkbox>` inside
  `<b-dropdown-form>`
- Directly you have to add `<b-form-checkbox>` inside `<b-dropdown>`

  ```
  <div id="app">
   <b-dropdown
     variant="transparent"
     text="Split Link"
     checkbox-menu
     allow-focus>
     <template #button-content>
       <span>
         <font-awesome-icon size="1x" :icon="['fas', 'filter']" />
       </span>
     </template>
     <b-dropdown-form>
       <b-form-checkbox
         id="checkbox-1"
         name="checkbox-1"
         value="accepted"
         unchecked-value="not_accepted">All
       </b-form-checkbox>
       <b-form-checkbox
         id="checkbox-2"
         name="checkbox-2"
         value="accepted1"
         unchecked-value="not_accepted2">Department
       </b-form-checkbox>
     </b-dropdown-form>
   </b-dropdown>
  </div>
  ```

Inside `<b-dropdown>` tag you can add only below mentioned child tags

- `<b-dropdown-item>`
- `<b-dropdown-item-text>`
- `<b-dropdown-divider>`
- `<b-dropdown-form>`
- `<b-dropdown-group>`
- `<b-dropdown-header>`

[DEMO Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-sunset-cj43w)

Answer (score 2):

You can't use `<b-checkbox>` inside of a `<b-dropdown-item>` than the complete "checkbox" is working like a `button`.

You just have to remove your `<b-dropdown-item>` like following:

```
<template>
  <div class="inventory-filter-button">
    <b-dropdown id=InventoryFilterButton variant="transparent"  text="Split Link" checkbox-menu allow-focus :right="right">
      <template #button-content>
        <span>
          <font-awesome-icon size="1x" :icon="['fas', 'filter']"/>
        </span>
      </template>
      <b-form-checkbox id="checkbox-1" v-model="status" name="checkbox-1" 
        value="accepted" unchecked-value="not_accepted"> All 
      </b-form-checkbox>
      <b-form-checkbox id="checkbox-1" v-model="status" name="checkbox-1"
        value="accepted" unchecked-value="not_accepted"> Department 
      </b-form-checkbox>
    </b-dropdown>
  </div>
</template>
```

You can also add `<b-dropdown-items>` but you have to set them seperate from the `b-form-checkbox` than these are all working like `buttons`.